# Perfect matching in a tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees, matching-theory

> Prove that in a tree there is at most $1$ perfect matching

If the number of vertices is even$\implies$ number of edges odd, not divisible by $2$, so no perfect matching

For the other case can you apply induction using $2$ leaves ?

Comment: It's an odd number of *vertices* which would imply no perfect matching, not an odd number of edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying induction by removing a leaf is the right idea. If $x$ is a leaf, and the edge meeting $x$ is $xy$, then any perfect matching for $T$ must consist of $xy$ together with a perfect matching of $T-\{x,y\}$. Now $T-\{x,y\}$ isn't necessarily a tree, but all of its components are trees.

Comment: You mean with curly braces the vertex set and not the edge, right ?

Comment: Yes, I mean the graph you get by removing those two vertices (and any edges that meet them).